# How to upgrade mac OS - currently having 10.5.8

Tags: osx-leopard

How do I know if 10.6 is right for my MAC? Where do I download it? Is it for free?

Answer (score 1):

It costs 29 USD/GBP/EUR as "Update Version", which is actually a full version with update pricing. It's only sold on a DVD which you need to order from Apple or get from a retail store.

The system requirements are [here](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html). If you have a model produced since mid 2006, or a Macbook/Macbook Pro, you're good.